# Help detecting target in pulsed radar signal

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, spectrogram, radar, doppler

This signal is from the Pasternack $2.4\textrm{ GHz}$ development kit.  The saved signal appears to be the pulsed waveform.  It is sampled at $20\textrm{ kHz}$ for $4130$ points.  I recorded a background signal, then aimed at a moving target ($\approx 20\textrm{ mph}$ vehicle).
[image]
My goal is to remove the background clutter and determine the velocity and range of the vehicle from this data.  So far I have had very little luck.  Here is what I have done:

1. Get the FFT of background and target signal
2. Remove the background clutter by subtracting in the frequency domain
3. Inverse the FFT
4. Split the signal into $n$ windows
5. Do the FFT of each and compare to find differences between each window

This method gives me velocities in the $100\textrm{ mph}$ range.  I also tried taking the difference between the background max frequency and target max frequency and still have incorrect velocities.  Are there any other methods to analyze this data?  I feel like the data as provided is useless because of the downsampling and also no time/delay info is included.

A copy of the raw data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Y5oa3OfT9GclhjbFVqdzJNTXZldE92Y1dYNUtteEozSlVn/view?usp=sharing).  I think the PRF is about $160\textrm{ Hz}$.

Comment: What exactly is the signal you've recorded? Is it raw receive signal in baseband? On an IF? Is it beat frequency? What bandwidth does Pasternack specify it should have?

Comment: its the raw receive signal - possibly beat frequency.  The manual doesn't specify this info and neither does the program or the output file.  I know the transmitted was 2.4GHz and the sampling rate is 20kHz.  I assume it would be a beat frequency since its the only way to recover the GHz signal.  I'm just not sure how to approach this - the fft has a high DC as well.